# QFileSystemWatcher: failed to add paths C: (can't watch Windows drives)

Tags: c++, file, qt

The following code raises `failed to add paths`.

```
auto f = new QFileSystemWatcher();
f->addPath("C:");
// Also tried f->addPath("C:/") and f->addPath("C:\\")
```

Adding paths like `C:/folder` works all right.

So I can't watch the Windows drives.

Comment: Technically yes. It appears in the application log. But this warning leads to an application error so that I can't watch the drives.

Comment: Do you have read access to C:?

Comment: >>Do you have read access to C:?
Yes

Comment: Try `"C:/windows"` and see if this works. Maybe the windows folder isn't "watchable", so drive C fails, too.

Comment: The `"C:\\"` and `"C:/"` forms work fine on my side with Qt 4.7.3 and 4.8 with mingw and MSVC without any warning or application log. What is your version? Can you make a release build and "Run as administrator" it?

Comment: @Hossein I have Qt 4.8.1. Relase build with administrator rights - nothing changed. Maybe it's because of my Windows Server OS, I'll try it on XP or 7.

Answer (score 0):

There is a system dependent limit to the number of files and directories that can be monitored simultaneously. If this limit has been reached, path will not be added to the file system watcher, and a warning message will be printed to stderr, which is `failed to add paths`.

Comment: That's definitely not it because I get this warning when the first directory is added. I can add 10 other non drive directories, and QFileSystemWatcher will work without any problems.

Comment: But still C:\\ can be too large to be monitored - I guess it's a recursive watch so the dirs and files in C:\\ counts as well. But it's just a guess based on @spyke 's answer.

Comment: @Viktor, it is not recursive.